# Random Direct in using header tags?

Tags: php

This is what I've tried so far, but this still isn't working properly.

http://pastebin.com/w2wRaR6r

Still it's not working and I can't find why. Help please?

I've tried changing the header location method with meta refresh but that requires it to be in head, I think. Anyway thanks.

Comment: Check my answer @iceybeta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple - you were using a single `=` sign which sets a value ~ you need to use 2 to test for equality ( and missing semi-colon )

```
<?php
    $r = rand(1, 3);
    if ($r == 1) header('Location:http://www.google.com/');
    if ($r == 2) header('Location:http://www.yahoo.com/');
    if ($r == 3) header('Location:http://www.bing.com/');
?>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `=` (which is assignment operator) and not `==` (which is comparison operator). It should be `==`:

```
<?php
$r = rand(1, 3);
if ($r == 1)
  header('Location:http://www.google.com/');
if ($r == 2)
  header('Location:http://www.yahoo.com/');
if ($r == 3)
  header('Location:http://www.bing.com/');
?>
```

Comment: Also a `;` semicolon is missing where you called `rand()`. Please use as above and check.